# Calculate p value of a t - statistic using the student_t_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to calculate p-values of a t-statistic for a two tailed test with 5% level of significance. And I wanted to do this with the standard library. I was wondering if this was possible using the `student_t_distribution` from the `< random >` module.
My code currently is as following

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    double t_stat = 0.0267; // t-statistic
    double alpha_los = 0.05; // level of significance
    double dof = 30; // degrees of freedom
    // calculate P > |t| and compare with alpha_los
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/student_t_distribution/
There is also an example usecase

Comment: @Unlikus , that is used for generating random numbers, and not calculating the p-value of a t-statistic.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. With `<random>` you can just sample data.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/students_t_dist.html can calculate the cdf then it es easy to get the p value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<random>` header just provides you with the ability to get random numbers from different distributions.

If you are able to use boost you can do the following:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/students_t.hpp>

int main() {
    double t_stat = 0.0267; // t-statistic
    double alpha_los = 0.05; // level of significance
    double dof = 30; // degrees of freedom
    boost::math::students_t dist(dof);

    double P_x_greater_t = 1.0 - boost::math::cdf(dist, t_stat);
    double P_x_smaller_negative_t = boost::math::cdf(dist, -t_stat);

    if(P_x_greater_t + P_x_smaller_negative_t < alpha_los) {
        
    } else {
        
    }
}
```